# Asciidoctorj doesn't work on WildFly 8.2.0.Final

Tags: wildfly, asciidoctor

I followed instruction of this document, but it doesn't work.

http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoctorj/#running-asciidoctorj-on-wildfly-as

First, I installed Asciidoctorj module into WildFly with jboss-cli:

```
module add \
 --name=org.asciidoctor \
 --resources=/tmp/asciidoctorj-1.5.2.jar,/tmp/jcommander-1.35.jar,/tmp/jruby-complete-1.7.16.1.jar \
 --resource-delimiter=, \
 --dependencies=javax.management.j2ee.api,javax.api
```

Then I deployed a simple WAR which contains a servlet which invokes `Asciidoctor.Factory.create()`. also I checked it contains `Dependencies: org.asciidoctor` in `MANIFEST.MF` surely. [whole project is available in my GitHub repo](https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/asciidoctortest).

But it doesn't work. what is wrong? is there anyone made Asciidoctorj work on WildFly?

my environment is:

- WildFly 8.2.0.Final
- Asciidoctorj 1.5.2
- Oracle JDK8u20

Here's stacktrace:

```
2015-01-12 23:23:06,764 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-3) UT005023: Exception handling request to /asciidoctortest-1.0-SNAPSHOT/: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.asciidoctor.internal.JRubyAsciidoctor
        at org.asciidoctor.Asciidoctor$Factory.create(Asciidoctor.java:647) [asciidoctorj-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
        at asciidoctortest.MyServlet.doGet(MyServlet.java:17) [classes:]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed a preceding stacktrace and I found a solution from it. It seems to that some dependencies were missing. also I got strange `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Unsafe` but I solved it too following [this conversation](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3445). now my module.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="org.asciidoctor">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="asciidoctorj-1.5.2.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jcommander-1.35.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="jruby-complete-1.7.16.1.jar"/>
    </resources>

    <dependencies>
        <module name="sun.jdk" export="true" >
            <imports>
                <include path="sun/misc/Unsafe" />
            </imports>
        </module>
        <module name="javax.management.j2ee.api"/>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="org.slf4j"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a new github project named asciidoctor-wildfly-docker in order to validate the required configuration to run Asciidoctor into WildFly.
This project gives you the possibility to execute tests into a Docker container and validate that Asciidoctor can convert AsciiDoc content to HTML and PDF output.

I'd love to have your feedback :
https://github.com/mgreau/asciidoctor-wildfly-docker

Maxime